# How to hide certain layers when rendering

Tags: rendering

I'm doing a transition effect in Blender 2.8 beta and I need help in rendering only the layers whereby my low poly character and the effect is on it and not the target object controlling the effect appearing alongside in the rendered animation. Please help, it's my assignment. Tq

Comment: Layers are now collections. Watch this rambling "tutorial": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jOO3K1B9vgg